# How to get the @sys-person entity to pickup lowercase names?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

How can I get the @sys-person entity to pickup lowercase names?

For example:

Bot:
May I get your first name please?

User:
My name is ben.

The bot doesn't pickup the lowercase name.

Is there a workaround for this?

Update:

I found a way to achieve this by using the string expression.

```
"<? @sys-person.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()+ @sys-person.substring(1)?>"
```

Comment: Does it work with "Ben"?

Comment: Yes, does. The issue is the user doesn't always cap the name.

Comment: Does it help when you turn on spellcheck? (In options.)

Comment: I actually found a way to do it with string expressions.